# Php query unable to load the query from get?id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to grab all the bidding bids amounts that were submitted and passed by the product ID, I can't seem to get it working can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

I have placed the view class for it to output and the query on the DB class

What I'm trying to do is to grab all the bids from the bids table and output to the screen
by passing the link where the user clicks on the product

---

```
<?php

class ProductView extends View {
    protected function displayContent() {
        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        //get the record from database
            $this -> product = $this -> model -> getProductByID($_GET['id']);
            $this -> bidprice = $this -> model ->allbids($_GET['id']);
                if(is_array($this -> product)) {
                    $html = $this -> displayProduct();
                    } else {

                       $html .= '<p>Sorry, that product is not available</p>';

                    }            
                        } else {
                         header("Location:index.php?page=error");

        }
            return $html;
    }


    private function displayProduct() {

            $html = '<div id="product">';
            $html .= '<img src="images/products/'.$this -> product['productImage'].'" alt="'.$this -> product['productName'].'" />';
            $html .= '<h3>'.$this -> product['productName'].'</h3>';
            $html .= '<p><strong>$'.$this -> product['productPrice'].'.00'.'</strong></p>';
            //.sprintf("%.2f" result was breaking the query placed .00. to give it currency rate.
            $html .= '<p>'.$this -> product['productDescription'].'</p>';
            $html .= '<p>'.$this -> bidprice['bidPrice'].'</p>';

            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .='<div id="space">';
            $html .='</div>';

        return $html;        
    }    
}



?>
```

---

DB query class

```
public function allbids($id){
        $qry = "SELECT userName , bidPrice as bidPrice FROM bids , users WHERE productID = $id";
        $rs = $this -> db -> query($qry);
        if($rs) {
            if($rs ->num_rows > 0) {
                $bid = $rs -> fetch_assoc();

            }
            return $bidPrice;

        } else {
            echo 'Error Executing Query';   
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, in the DB query class you are returning an unset variable. ($bidPrice). Should be $bid i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have fetched single record from the bid table also allbids function seems incorrect, kindly try with the below code and let me know whether working that for you or not.

```
<?php

class ProductView extends View {
protected function displayContent() {
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    //get the record from database
        $this -> product = $this -> model -> getProductByID($_GET['id']);
        $this -> bidprice = $this -> model ->allbids($_GET['id']);
            if(is_array($this -> product)) {
                $html = $this -> displayProduct();
                } else {

                   $html .= '<p>Sorry, that product is not available</p>';

                }            
                    } else {
                     header("Location:index.php?page=error");

    }
        return $html;
}


private function displayProduct() {

        $html = '<div id="product">';
        $html .= '<img src="images/products/'.$this -> product['productImage'].'" alt="'.$this -> product['productName'].'" />';
        $html .= '<h3>'.$this -> product['productName'].'</h3>';
        $html .= '<p><strong>$'.$this -> product['productPrice'].'.00'.'</strong></p>';
        //.sprintf("%.2f" result was breaking the query placed .00. to give it currency rate.
        $html .= '<p>'.$this -> product['productDescription'].'</p>';
        /* here you have to place a for each loop that will fetch all the info for bid*/
        foreach($this -> bidprice as $val)
        {
            $html .= '<p> Bid Price'.$val['bidPrice'].'</p>';
            $html .= '<p> Bidded By'.$val['userName'].'</p>';
        }

        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .='<div id="space">';
        $html .='</div>';

    return $html;        
}
```

}

```
// your db function
public function allbids($id){
    $qry = "SELECT userName , bidPrice as bidPrice FROM bids , users WHERE productID = $id";
    $rs = $this -> db -> query($qry);
    if($rs) {
        if($rs ->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
            {
                $bid[]= $row;
            }

        }
        return $bid[];

    } else {
        echo 'Error Executing Query';   
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: @JacksonYong: did you get the idea why that is been not working for you? because you are taking only one bid from bid table while you have to fetch all bids and show that by doing a loop on display function.
Though if you are not clear let me know I will do help by editing your code files.

Comment: yeah sorry im still not clear:( im new to php please can you teach me

Comment: @JacksonYong: sure, how can I check your code and how can I teach you?

Comment: because of i didnt place foreach loop ?

Comment: @JacksonYong : yes because lack of for loop that issue is there, if you want I can solve this issue share your files and db structure with me.

Comment: its just those 2 code one is the view class which extends for it and the other was the db class which was query function to execute the query

Comment: @JacksonYong: share your code on either drop box or media fire I will take a look and solve that and resend the code to you. You can also share your gmail/skype id with me.